# Поворот объекта в сторону игрока

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно, чтобы враг поворачивался в сторону игрока только по горизонтали (3д игра).
Много способов пробовал и лучше всего работает этот:

```
transform.LookAt(player.position);
```

Но он поворачивает объект и по вертикали. Как сделать поворот только по горизонтали?

Comment: Замените z-координату player.position на ноль или z-координату самого врага

Comment: чтобы принять ответ, нужно пометить его зеленой галочкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В компоненте **RigidBody** в инспекторе можно "заморозить" вращение объекта по осям X Y Z, поставив галочку на соответствующую ось.

Чтобы поворачивать объект только по горизонтали, нужно поставить галочки на X Z оси.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну по идее то да, но... https://snipboard.io/LGZDJm.jpg

Comment: попробуй transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.rotation.y, 0);

Comment: да, уже сделал, помогло